# DefineConstants in csproj file if I have a reference to some dll

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

I want to define msbuild constant with a condition:

```
<DefineConstants Condition="if have a reference to MyTest.dll">TEST</DefineConstants>


    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="System" />
      <Reference Include="System.Core" />
      <Reference Include="MyTest.dll" />
   </ItemGroup>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594366/how-do-i-do-a-msbuild-condition-testing-if-an-itemgroup-contains-an-item) for how to use a condition like 'does my item group contain item X?'. However as noted there that doesn't work when called in the global scope, it must be done within a Target. So you have to add such Target and make it run automatically before the build starts:

```
<Target Name="AdjustDefineConstants" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants Condition="'%(Reference.Identity)' == 'Mytest.dll'">TEST</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="DefineConstants is now $(DefineConstants)"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see it is working inside msbuild target.  But I need it to work inside a csproj file.  It is not working for me.

Comment: Why do you think you need it outside of a Target? Moreover, not 100% sure, but I think that is simply impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but you need to work around the restriction that conditional expressions on `PropertyGroup` and `ItemGroup` elements outside of Targets have some restrictions when accessing item metadata.

You can leverage `ItemGroup` expansion by simply concatenating an item group to a scalar property. Here I basically glue `_DefineConstants` onto the back of `DefineConstants`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="MyTest.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="@(Reference->AnyHaveMetadataValue('Identity', 'MyTest.dll'))">
    <_DefineConstants Include="Test" />
  </ItemGroup>  

  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);@(_DefineConstants)</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Build">  
    <Message Text="DefineConstants: $(DefineConstants)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

This will print `";Test"`

[image]